# Configuring Blackfire on a base virtual box using Chef

Tags: profiling, vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning, vagrantfile

I'm trying to give Blackfire.io (by Sensiolabs) a try to profile an existing PHP application running on a Vagrant machine (with PHP 5.3) on Mac.

I'm using Chef to provision my machine with Blackfire, but when running "vagrant provision" I get the following error:

> default: STDERR: The server ID parameter is not set. Please run
>   blackfire-agent -register to configure it.

..which I already did

This is my Vagrant file:

```
is_windows = (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    ..

    config.vm.box = "covex/ubuntu1204-x64"

    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.json = {
         :blackfire => {
          :'server-id' => "d4860b49-be67-404b-9fa1-b..",
          :'server-token' => "c412751f30d6c724033d8408e.."
         }
      }
      chef.add_recipe "blackfire"
  end
end
```

I followed the installation steps on https://blackfire.io/getting-started, except for the Probe paragraph.

Is my Vagrant file wrongly configured, so it can't read the server ID and token? Is the "brew install blackfire-php53" needed for this, if so, is there a way to configure this through my Vagrant file?

Comment: You should add to issue description what cookbook are you using and the version.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you are using https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/blackfire

You missed the `agent` node in the config tree

```
{
  "blackfire" => {
    "agent" => {
      "server-id" => "your server-id",
      "server-token" => "your server-token",
    }
  }
}
```